# Get-ChildItem -Recurse throws System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: function, powershell, memory, memory-management

I run this function on a big directory:

*Definition*

```
# (searches for all ips within files in the current directory recursively)

function searchips
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$dir = $(pwd)
    )

    ls -Recurse -Force `
    | Select-String -Pattern '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' -AllMatches `
    | ? { 
        $matches = ($_.Matches | Select-Object -Unique)
        return $matches.Count -gt 1 -or $matches[0].Value -ne '127.0.0.1' 
    } `
    | select Path,Matches,FileName,LineNumber,Line `
    | Format-Table -AutoSize `
    | Out-String -Width 4096
}
```

*Call*

```
PS C:\path\to\huge> searchips hugeDirectory >> outfile.txt
```

But I get this error every single time:

```
out-lineoutput : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
At C:\Users\myUserName\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:73 char:2
+     ls -Recurse `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [out-lineoutput], OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand
```

Currently my PS memory settings look like this:

```
   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Shell

Name                      Value         Type
----                      -----         ----
AllowRemoteShellAccess    true          System.String
IdleTimeout               7200000       System.String
MaxConcurrentUsers        10            System.String
MaxShellRunTime           2147483647    System.String
MaxProcessesPerShell      25            System.String
MaxMemoryPerShellMB       9000000       System.String
MaxShellsPerUser          30            System.String
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have 72 lines. The error message doesn't match the code either.

Comment: I agree with @AnsgarWiechers, the error message references some sort of `out-lineoutput` function, and you are showing us neither the definition nor the invocation of it. Additionally, the "memory settings" you're showing are for WSMan, which would matter if you were using PowerShell remoting, however you aren't (and that error message would be different than the one shown here).

Comment: Try using `Out-String` with the `Stream` switch.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It is line 72 within my `profile.ps1`. I figured I wouldn't post the entire file because I am only calling `searchips`

Comment: @briantist I'm guessing `out-lineoutput` has something to do with `Out-String`. I did not know those memory settings were for remoting shell sessions. Is there another one for non-remote?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and show that sample code as well as the error message it produces.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Could you explain in detail how this is "not verifiable"? I have provided sample code and the error message. To test this all you have to do is copy and paste my function into powershell and type `searchips`. If I minify my function anymore it won't produce the results that I'm looking for

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It sounds more like you don't believe that is the error I'm getting from this function. If you'd like I can screenshot me getting the definition of `searchips` calling it and getting the error all in one take?

Comment: It's not verifiable in that a) the error message still doesn't match your code (and not just because of the line number) and b) I was unable to reproduce the behavior you described on 2 different systems (Windows 7 and Server 2012 R2, both with PowerShell v4). Did you try running just the code you posted in a vanilla PowerShell (without profile)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'll give it a shot in vanilla real quick.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Tried it in vanilla, no difference. I believe the issue is that my folder is ` ~1700MB'. If I call the function like `searchips` instead of `searchips >> outfile.txt` it will actually quit powershell in the middle of outputing all the matches which is really odd. I wonder if the error I posted in my question was caused by the `>>` trying to put it into a file

Comment: You're right. I was able to reproduce the behavior now. My mistake was that I didn't realize that your function ignores the `$dir` parameter and always works on the current directory. Hence it always worked when I ran `searchips C:\path\to\largefolder >> outfile.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by `Out-String`. The cmdlet merges its input to a single string (before returning that string to the caller). To do so it must collect all output in memory. Kinda obvious, now that I think about it.

I'd recommend using `ConvertTo-Csv` instead of `Format-Table | Out-String`. It avoids memory exhaustion, and it's a lot easier to use the output for further processing.

```
function Find-IPAddresses {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -LiteralPath $_})]
        [string]$dir = $PWD.Path
    )

    Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse -Force |
        Select-String -Pattern '\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}' -AllMatches |
        Where-Object {
            $matches = ($_.Matches | Select-Object -Unique)
            $matches.Count -gt 1 -or $matches[0].Value -ne '127.0.0.1'
        } |
        Select-Object Path, Matches, FileName, LineNumber, Line |
        ConvertTo-Csv -NoType
}

Find-IPAddresses 'C:\some\folder' > 'outfile.csv'
```

Or don't return text output at all. Just return the list of objects, and do all formatting/outputting when you call the function and know what you want to do with the data:

```
function Find-IPAddresses {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -LiteralPath $_})]
        [string]$dir = $PWD.Path
    )

    Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse -Force |
        Select-String -Pattern '\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}' -AllMatches |
        Where-Object {
            $matches = ($_.Matches | Select-Object -Unique)
            $matches.Count -gt 1 -or $matches[0].Value -ne '127.0.0.1'
        } |
        Select-Object Path, Matches, FileName, LineNumber, Line
}

Find-IPAddresses 'C:\some\folder' | Export-Csv 'outfile.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: It worked. Turns out it was dying because it found 350,000+ IP Addresses and probably keeping all of that in memory.. Thank you, the script runs much faster now

Comment: Also, my bad about the parameter portion of the function. I thought if you fed it a directory is would use that one instead of always using `pwd`. Gotta fix that

Comment: No worries. I should have noticed that much earlier.